# Unity: Making spotlight range decrease overtime

Tags: c#

so i'm looking to use a Flashlight system in Unity that decreases the range on the flashlight when it's being used, and then when it's turned off it "recharges" and the range increases. I have absolutely no idea what i'm doing but have this really basic layout that i'm hoping someone on here could expand on, thanks!

```
public class Flashlight : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float minRange = 20;
    public float maxRange = 100;
    public Light light;    

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {      
            light.enabled = !light.enabled;      
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to decide on how fast the flashlight should discharge (eg, loose range) and write a simple logic in update (or as a coroutine) to corespond to this.

Something along the lines of

```
light.radius = maxRange-ElapsedTime*x;
```